# Angularjs: Binding in ui-routing nested state not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a these **states** in my app config:

```
 ...
 .state('register', {
    templateUrl: 'views/register/register.html',
    controller: "registerCtrl"
  })
  .state('register.step-one', {
    url: "/register.one",
    templateUrl: "views/register/register.one.html",
    controller: "registerOneCtrl"
  })
  .state('register.step-two', {
    url: "/register.two",
    templateUrl: "views/register/register.two.html",
    controller: "registerTwoCtrl"
  })
```

My main controller is this **registerCtrl**:

```
$scope.studies = [];
$scope.newStudy = "dd";

$scope.addStudy = function (studyName) {
  $scope.studies.push({
    title: studyName
  });
  console.log($scope.newStudy); //This prints empty
  $scope.newStudy = "AAAAA"; //this doesn't seem to work :(
  console.log($scope.newStudy);
}
```

And I have this in my **register.two** template:

```
<div class="container-fluid  margin-top-md">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newStudy"/>
  <i class="fa fa fa-plus-square" ng-click="addStudy(newStudy)"></i>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="study in studies">
      <input type="text" ng-model="study.title"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, this is not working fine because after a study is added, I would like to update my newStudy input field, however, I'm unable to do so, because that variable doesn't seem to affect my template.

If I place my controller code inside registerTwoCtrl, then it works fine. How can I make this work using a single controller (The parent controller)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of failing to use the ng-model Golden Rule of Thumb:

> Always have a "." in your ng-model expression

If you store the `newStudy` as a property of an object on the `$scope` in `registerCtrl`, it will work fine.

e.g.

In registerCtrl:

```
$scope.data = { newStudy: "AAAA" }; // instead of $scope.newStudy = "AAAA";
```

In the template, change it to:

```
<div class="container-fluid  margin-top-md">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.newStudy"/>
  <i class="fa fa fa-plus-square" ng-click="addStudy(data.newStudy)"></i>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="study in studies">
      <input type="text" ng-model="study.title"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

A possibly better alternative is to use the `controller as` syntax. Look it up, it will help eliminate these kinds of errors because you will then be referring to `registerCtrl.newStudy` instead of just `newStudy` in your ng-model expression.